# Highcharts - The image cannot show under xAxis.labels with vue.js wrapper

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Basically I want to achieve something like this:
Put a Custom Image Icon on a specific label under xAxis in Column chart.
[image]

And this is the working example I built in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1t94gzkp/14/)

But some how When I using `vue-highcharts v0.0.10` wrapper the icon couldn't show up, what's the issue here?

I tried setup the margin or messing up with the formatter, no luck.
And why the stackoverflow requires long description for this question just because the code is very looooonnnnggggg?????

```
options() {
  return {
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
    title: {
      text: null,
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: null,
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Worst', 'Average', 'You|||', 'Best'],
      lineWidth: 0,
      minorTickLength: 0,
      tickLength: 0,
      labels: {
        formatter: function() { //eslint-disable-line
          if (this.value.includes('|||')) {
            // const avatar = this.value.split('|||')[1];
            // const name = this.value.split('|||')[0]; //eslint-disable-line
            return '<img src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 32px; height: 32px"/>';
          }
          return this.value;
        },
        useHTML: true,
      },
    },
    yAxis: {
      visible: false,
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    colors: [this.orange, this.yellow, this.lightGreen, this.green],
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        shadow: true,
        pointWidth: 30,
        showInLegend: false,
        colorByPoint: true,
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderRadius: 5,
        enableMouseTracking: false,
      },
    },
    series: [
      {
        data: [this.worstScore, this.averageScore, this.yourScore, this.bestScore],

      },
    ],
  };
```

This is the actual behavior:

[image]

Comment: Why do not you use the [official package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-vue) ?

Comment: can you post jsfiddle of the not working one too?

Comment: @pooyan jsfiddle seems does not support with vue component setup, in short. I don't know how to post that one to jsfiddle

Comment: @Core972 I didn't set that up bro